# Python + SQL (SUBSTRING + SUM)

Tags: python, sqlite

I have table that looks like this:

```
[Things]
id             date             number          name
------------------------------------------------------------
1              2000-11-20       11              Joe
2              1999-10-13       12              Lis
3              1999-11-11       13              Jhonson
------------------------------------------------------------
```

And I need to make this program where I use Python and SQL to calculate sum of every number on that list while using only the year as filter.
Problem is that I never have done python and I have hard time implementing SQL in java without any guidance so I just started learning the python basics. (This is beginner SQL course that I'm doing so the main point is not in learning python, but what ever)
I came up with this:

```
year = input("Give the year: ")
        arvo = db.execute("SELECT number,SUBSTRING (date, 1, 4) FROM Things").fetchall()
```

So now I have list of numbers and years so I could quite easily count the sum now but I'm not quite sure how you do it in Python. If anyone knows way to filter it further in SQL that would be way better also! Thanks in advance! I know I could use "if year in arvo" to check if there is right year in row but for some reason I struggle with each row (for x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must filter the table for the year that you get as input and use `SUM()` aggregate function to get the result:

```
vuosi= input("Give the year: ")
sql = """
SELECT SUM(number) AS total 
FROM Things
WHERE SUBSTR(date, 1, 4) = ? 
"""
arvo = db.execute(sql, (vuosi,)).fetchone()
total_sum = arvo[0]
```

Comment: Thank you. I played around with this for a moment and one question popped into my mind. Why do you need to add comma on (vuosi, ) for this to work?

Comment: @HuManatee the 2nd argument of `execute()` is a list of values that you pass to replace the ? placeholders. Since there is only 1 value to pass for the ? placeholder in this case, a comma must be used so that a list (of only 1 value) is created.

Comment: Super! This was very useful post for me this evening. Helped me to get grip on how to write clean python + SQL. Got me through my assignments. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using sqlite.
Try using this SQL query:

```
SELECT SUM(number) FROM Things
WHERE strftime('%Y', date) = year
```

The python code would be:

```
arvo = db.execute("SELECT SUM(number) FROM Things WHERE YEAR(date) = ?", (int(vuosi),)).fetchone()[0]
```

Comment: I tried this also, but I got error when using "YEAR". Looked neat though.

Comment: I've updated my answer, hopefully now it works in sqlite.

Answer (score 1):

```
vuosi= input("Give the year: ")
sql = f"""
SELECT SUM(number) AS sum
FROM Things
WHERE SUBSTRING(date, 1, 4) = {vuosi} 
"""
```

Execute from here.
The year input is filled in the SQL query.